# Do call ids in twilio always start with 'CA'

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We're planning on saving the twilio call ids on our side for specific reasons. For efficiency, it would better for us to store them as uuid instead of varchar.

From our tests, the call ids we are getting are 34 characters long and start with 'CA'. We want to know if this is always the case.

Is it safe for us to store the 32-character id (without first two characters) in our database as uuid? Will this be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I contacted Twilio support since we were really avoiding storing the ids as varchar. And as mentioned, there's nothing in the documentation about the id.

Turns out they say it's safe to store the last 32 characters. So we'd be able to save it as uuid and it'd be more efficient when saving, fetching records.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any info in the docs so my sugestion is. DON'T DO IT.

If it's not specified in the docs that the "accountsid" is unique without the letter (CA), then they are free to not have them unique.

Maybe it works, maybe it keeps working, but one they it may not work and you are going to spend lots of resources hunting down the bug. Then you will regret not saving the full 34 characters long line just to save a few bytes.